# Spring Web Service accessing Osgi bundles deployed in Tomcat

Tags: spring, web-services, maven, tomcat, osgi

I have been tasked with looking at redesigning our current web service.

As a lot of the development of our main/legacy products was done using OSGi, we currently have a web service which is developed using osgi bundles and deployed using Talend.

Some of our newer products are being developed around Spring/Maven/Tomcat so I have been asked to investigate moving our web service to this technology stack.

What is required is a Spring contract first Web Service which can access the main business code, **which will still be in its OSGi bundles**, all packaged neatly in a war 
 to be deployed in Tomcat.

Is this possible? 
Most pages I have seen seem to be pointing at using Virgo but our hope was to cut down on the technologies used, not to add others

Comment: just make sure your war does contain a valid OSGi-Manifest. As Talend uses Karaf inside you could go ahead and test it with a plain Karaf server if needed.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back ... busy, busy.

Went with a different solution.
Virgo which handles all the OSGI bundles and handles a separate war file for the web service.
The two talk through rmi.
Many thanks.